# Inspector value cannot access from another class in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two classes. One called **GameManager** and another one **Enemies**. 
I have two variables in **GameManager** which I have changed from inspector `currentLevel=1` and `totalEnemy=10.`

```
// GameManager.cs
    private static GameManager instance = new GameManager();
    public static GameManager get(){ return instance; }

    public int currentLevel;
    public int curLevel { get; set; }
    public int totalEnemy;
    public int totLevel { get; set; }


    void Start () {
        curLevel = currentLevel;
        totLevel = totalEnemy;
    }
```

I'm trying to access these two variable from **Eneimes** class like this; but everytime it gives me `curLevel = 0`, but I'm expecting to get `curLevel = 1`. What I'm doing wrong?

```
// Enemies.cs

    void Start () {
        Debug.Log (GameManager.get().curLevel); // always output = 0
    }
```

Comment: You seem to have changed 'currentLevel', you have to change 'instance'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `private static GameManager instance = new GameManager();` is the issue.

When a script is attached to a `GameObject`, an instance of the type of the script is referenced as `this` inside the script. In other words, there can be multiple instances of same type if the same script is attached to multiple `GameObject`s.

Therefore, ***the specific instance*** that have `curLevel = 1` as you set in the Inspector is **an instance** of the type attached to ***the specific*** `GameObject`. This means the one should be referred to as `this` inside the script.

If you declare a new instance of `GameManager` as in your code, you are basically ignoring all values in the Inspector because the `static GameManager instance` is pointing to a different instance than ***the instance*** you set values for in the Inspector.

In order to use the specific instance that you declared using the Inspector, you should do the following.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static GameManager instance;
    public static GameManager get() { return instance; }

    public int currentLevel;
    public int curLevel { get; set; }
    public int totalEnemy;
    public int totLevel { get; set; }

    void Awake()
    {
       if (instance == null) 
       {
          instance = this;
       }
       else 
       {
          Debug.LogError(string.Format("GameManager.Awake(): More than one instances of this type {0} is being initialised but it's meant to be Singleton and should not be initialised twice. It is currently being initialised under the GameObject {1}.", this.GetType(), this.gameObject.name));
          Destroy(gameObject);
       }

        curLevel = currentLevel;
        totLevel = totalEnemy;
    }
}
```

Note that I changed `Start()` to `Awake()`. This is because you are referring to values initiliased in this method from other scripts, and you cannot guarantee which `Start()` is called first between different `MonoBehaviours` in the runtime. However, Unity guarantees that `Awake()` is always called earlier than `Start()`. Further, it is Unity's best practice to initialise self-initialisable variables in `Awake()`, and initialise variables dependent on other scripts in `Start()` because of this execution order.

Lastly, there will be problems when there are multiple `GameObject` that has `GameManager` as its component in your scene. Consider a case where you have two such objects. when the scene is loaded, each of the script will call `Awake()`, and both of them will set `private static GameManager instance;` to each of the two `this`. The result would be one is overriden by another.

You could say that you will be careful to use this script and make sure only one `GameObject` has this script as its component. However, you should always write your code as if someone who do not know about your code can use it without thinking, and stupid mistakes of other people new to the project could be ***easily detected***.

EDIT:

To respond to the OP's comment, I added code to handle when this type is initialised more than once in the project. In addition to [@Kardux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5539543/kardux)'s suggestion, I added `Debug.LogError()` because I do not want the project to ***silently*** solve things. If a problem happens, I want to get notified of it.

If you are using `Singleton`s frequently in your project, you might want to have a parent `abstract class Singleton` that handles this instance checking process for all child `Singleton`s, and have `GameManager` inherit from `Singleton`.

However, use `Singleton` with care as it is considered a bad design pattern if misused. (And I don't know how to use it properly so I avoid using it.)

Comment: awesome explanation!! u also cleared my doubt about the use of Awake() and Start(). about the part of making sure only once instance of this script in entire project, any idea how to implement that? I use DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject); is that right approach for this

Comment: A good practice when using instances is also to check if instance exists already (in case you only want one as the singleton approach): `if(instance == null) { instance = this; } else { DestroyImmediate(gameobject); }`. This can save you headaches in case you forget to remove the component from the other scenes of your game :)

Comment: @jquery404 I'm glad it helped. Please see the edited answer.